# "def" invalid syntax in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, time, timezone

I'm using Visual Studio Code for a python program and getting an error of "def" as invalid syntax.
Please Solve this problem.
This my code :

```
def time():
    tz = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
    st = ("And Now its ?")
    print(st+tz.strftime('%#I%M%p'))
```

Error I'm getting :

```
def time():
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You need to indent the lines that consist the body of your function

Comment: not handy to name your function the same as a library module

Comment: Bro I have intended the code but still its giving the same error

Comment: @17_Ronstark_04 hi, could you provide a picture of the VSCode? And please include the 'PROBLEMS' panel.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation isn't proper dear.

Also it isn't ideal to name the function as of a module.

In Python3 functions code needs to be Indented.

Make it.

```py
def time():
    tz = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
    st = ("Now its")
    print(st+tz.strftime('%#I%M%p'))
```

Now it's working fine

In Python3 proper indentation  is very important.

Comment: Bro I have intended the code but still its giving the same error

Comment: What?
Which python version are you using @17_Ronstark_04

Answer (score 0):

In Python all of the function body has to be indented.

```
def time():
    tz = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
    st = ("Now its")
    print(st+tz.strftime('%#I%M%p'))
```